# Authlogic: Assuring that a user can't log in twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, authlogic

Is there an easy way in [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/tree/master) (haven't found nothing browsing [the docs](http://authlogic.rubyforge.org/)) to
assure that a UserSession can't be created if the User already has an UserSession object?

In other words: I want to make sure that a user can't log in twice with the same credentials.

UPDATE: Check the comments on thief's answer to find the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your user sessions controller:

```
    before_filter :require_no_user, :only => [:new, :create]
```

in your app controller:

```
def require_no_user
  if current_user
    store_location
    flash[:notice] = "You must be logged out to access this page"
    redirect_to account_url
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: In addition, it's probably best to hide the login links as well, when someone is logged in.

Comment: @thief: Could you elaborate? I don't understand how this will keep X to log in as Alice on client B while Y is already logged in as Alice on client A.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. In this case a callback is the way to go. eg: in your UserSessionModel use the callback 'before_persisting' to check if the account is logged in on another machine with the AuthLogic method 'logged_in?' - http://authlogic.rubyforge.org/classes/Authlogic/ActsAsAuthentic/LoggedInStatus/Methods/InstanceMethods.html::

Answer (score 0):

To my mind a cleaner approach is to use callbacks in the UserSession class. Like, you can define a before_create callback there, and mark the model as invalid in appropriate case. Haven't tried this out myself, though. Here are [the docs for the Callbacks module](http://authlogic.rubyforge.org/classes/Authlogic/Session/Callbacks.html).

Comment: Yes, but you can use your require_no_user method anywhere that it is required that a user is not logged in, also it pairs well with its opposite: require_user

Comment: I agree. Nothing to add here.